# Gmail Canned Response only for original message

Tags: gmail, gmail-canned-response

My business uses Gmail's canned response feature to autoreply to all incoming messages and it works great. However, it keeps sending the canned response for every single message received in a single email thread. How do I configure the canned responses so that it only replies to the original email, instead of every follow-up email reply?

Any help is appreciated!